# angular.js:12520Error: [$injector:unpr]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service, angularjs-factory

i am new to angularjs, i am working on a application which uses token based authentication process, i have created a authentication service through which i get the token but when i use this service in other controller i am getting **$injector:unpr** error any help would be appreciable.

my service : authService.js

```
var app = angular.module('loginFormApp', []);
 app.controller('loginFormCtrl', function ($scope, AuthService) {
     $scope.loginCall = function () {
         AuthService.authentication($scope.loginId, $scope.password).then(function (token) {
             //AuthService.getToken();            
         });


     };
 });

 app.factory('AuthService', function ($http) {
     var cachedToken;
     return {
         authentication: function (UserName, Password) {
             return $http.post("http://103.19.89.152:8080/ccp-services/authenticate", {
                     'userName': UserName,
                     'password': Password
                 })
                 .then(function (response) {
                         window.location.href = "http://192.168.1.148:2000/angular/dashboard.html";
                         cachedToken = response.data.httpHeaders.h5cAuthToken;
                         return cachedToken;
                         //   alert(token);

                     },
                     // Error Handling
                     function (response) {
                         console.log(response.datas);
                     });

         },
         getToken: function() {
             //alert(cachedToken);
             return cachedToken;

         }

     }
 });
```

my dashboard controller : dashboard.html

```
<script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', ['loginFormApp']);
        app.controller('dashboardFormCtrl', function($scope, $http, AuthService) {
            var config = {
                headers: {
                    'h5cAuthToken': AuthService.getToken(),
                    'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'
                }
            };
            //alert(config.headers.h5cAuthToken);

            $http.get("http://103.19.89.152:8080/ccp-services/dashboardearnfit/fetch", config).success(function(data) {

                $scope.dashboardData = data;
                                });


        });

    </script>
```

it's redirecting to the dashboard page but the webservices i am using in that pages not working due to the **token**

error :

```
Navigated to http://192.168.1.148:2000/angular/dashboard.html
dashboard.html:126 GET http://192.168.1.148:2000/angular/%7B%7BdashboardData.singleResult.userProfile.memberPhotoPath%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)
dashboard.html:216 GET http://192.168.1.148:2000/angular/%7B%7Bactivityitem.participantPicPath%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)
dashboard.html:289 GET http://192.168.1.148:2000/angular/%7B%7BchallengeItem.participantPicPath%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)
jquery-migrate-1.1.0.min.js:1'//@ sourceURL' and '//@ sourceMappingURL' are deprecated, please use '//# sourceURL=' and '//# sourceMappingURL=' instead.
angular.js:10765 GET http://103.19.89.152:8080/ccp-services/dashboardearnfit/fetch 403 (Forbidden)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:10765r @ angular.js:10558g @ angular.js:10268(anonymous function) @ angular.js:14792$eval @ angular.js:16052$digest @ angular.js:15870$apply @ angular.js:16160(anonymous function) @ angular.js:1679e @ angular.js:4523c @ angular.js:1677yc @ angular.js:1697Zd @ angular.js:1591(anonymous function) @ angular.js:29013b @ angular.js:3057If @ angular.js:3346d @ angular.js:3334
```

Comment: Can you post the complete error code?

Comment: @Itsik, i have update the post with the error

Comment: Try creating the 'dashboardFormCtrl' without <script> tags(like the rest of your controlers).

Comment: Please create plnkr or fiddle.

Comment: @itsik, i have created dashboardFormCtrl in the same file called dashboard.html, do you want me to create a seperate file dashboardFormCtrl.js and include the script into the dashboard.html

Comment: No just add it to the file whrer your factory and controlller are.

Comment: @ItsikMauyhas, i have update the code but same error occurs

Comment: you have defined your app twice. once with 'myApp' and another with 'loginFormApp', I dont think it is possible to share factories like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing following lines possibly it requires promise then `success`

```
$http.get("http://103.19.89.152:8080/ccp-services/dashboardearnfit/fetch", config).then(function(data) {
    $scope.dashboardData = data;
});
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are injecting a module that is not available. In this case it looks like 'AuthService' is not available when you try to inject as a dependency.

You have declared two separate applications (dependencies will not be shared in that case).

1: This is a module 'setter' with array syntax.

```
var app = angular.module('loginFormApp', []);
```

2: This is also a module setter with array syntax.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

Change 2: to a getter, this means the applications will share modules.

```
var app = angular.module('loginFormApp');
```

Or restructure your modules/application dependencies.

Comment: i have two different pages login.html and dashboard.html so should i have to use same module name in both the pages like var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

Comment: i have edited in authService.js and login.html and make same module name in both files called myApp please see the updated authService.js

Comment: First : the 404 responses : http://192.168.1.148:2000/angular/%7B%7BdashboardData.singleResult.userProfile.memberPhotoPath%7D%7D. %7B stands for '{'. My guess is that you have some image like this : `<img src="{{dashboardData.singleResult.userProfile.memberPhotoPat}}" />` use `ng-src` instead :  `<img ng-src="dashboardData.singleResult.userProfile.memberPhotoPat" />`. Second 403 means Forbidden, check your server's logs.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you used ng-app like this :

```
ng-app="myApp"
```

Then you must link module using dependencies :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['loginFormApp']);
```

Or the injector of the module 'myApp' will know nothing about loginFormApp

Comment: i link the module using dependencies,  as it removes the $injector:unpr error but error 403 comes, as i update in the code

Comment: as it navigates to the dashboard.html page but getToken() function returns undefined object

Answer (score 0):

You can inject 'AuthService' like below:

```
var app = angular.module('loginFormApp', []);
 app.controller('loginFormCtrl',['$scope', 'AuthService', function ($scope, AuthService) {
     $scope.loginCall = function () {
         AuthService.authentication($scope.loginId, $scope.password).then(function (token) {
             //AuthService.getToken();            
         });


     };
 }]);

 app.factory('AuthService', function ($http) {
     var cachedToken;
     return {
         authentication: function (UserName, Password) {
             return $http.post("http://103.19.89.152:8080/ccp-services/authenticate", {
                     'userName': UserName,
                     'password': Password
                 })
                 .then(function (response) {
                         window.location.href = "http://192.168.1.148:2000/angular/dashboard.html";
                         cachedToken = response.data.httpHeaders.h5cAuthToken;
                         return cachedToken;
                         //   alert(token);

                     },
                     // Error Handling
                     function (response) {
                         console.log(response.datas);
                     });

         },
         getToken: function() {
             //alert(cachedToken);
             return cachedToken;

         }

     }
 });
```